# Toolbar in AppBarLayout is not scrolling off if Translucent Navigation is true

Tags: android, scroll, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

**UPDATE:** here is an [example app](https://github.com/karray/AndroidToolbarScrolling). I've tested it on my Nexus 6P, Android 6.0.1

I'm using `CoordinatorLayout` and `RecyclerView`.
If `<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>` toolbar is not hiding (but it is scrollable itself). appcompat is v7:23.2.1

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If I add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to `AppBarLayout` it works with some issues.

Is there any solution?

System bar overlays toolbar
[image]

There are top and bottom paddings
[image]

And `CoordinatorLayout` (perhaps) scrolls with toolbar
[image]

Comment: Could you find solution to the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Seems this is a bug. I found a temporary solution for the problem.

Get rid of all **android:fitsSystemWindows** in Coordinator Layout and its children, or set them to **false**. And then add the height of statusbar to your toolbar's height and top padding manually in your activity:

```
toolbar.setPadding(0, getStatusBarHeight(), 0, 0);
toolbar.getLayoutParams().height = toolbar.getLayoutParams().height + getStatusBarHeight();
```

The method to get statusbar height:

```
public int getStatusBarHeight() {
    int height = 0;
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return height;
}
```

With these changes, toolbar is scrolling properly, and it has proper height.